# Updating Excel Connection using SharePoint Excel Services

Tags: sharepoint-server, excel-services, project-server

I am developing a **SharePoint Webpart**, which asks user for basic information and SQL Connection. As user fills information and click's Generate Report button an excel report is generated which has **"External Connection"** in it. I have to update that External Connection (Probably SQL Connection) which the user has provided in the webpart.

**NOTE:** I am using **Excel Services** for doing any change in workbook.

**In short, Can we update connection string (Data Source, Initial Catalog, etc) of Excel File using Excel Service?**

[image: Connection Properties Dialog]

As shown in the above image. I have to update the highlighted text.